getting some values from the table list in web browse of the machine
In my workplace, I want to read the temperature information of a remote machine connected to the network. While connected to the machine, I share the web page image and page source image. I am trying to do this with JSOUP, but unfortunately I have not been successful. When opening the page, first a landing page and then tables with data appear. thanks a lot in advance.
-------------------------HTML SOURCE----------------------
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script src="js/LIBRARY.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="js/config.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
<body id="BODY">
    <table id="INIT" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;height:100%;color:White;visibility:visible">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">
                <table style="font-size:32px;font-family:Freestyle Script;font-weight:bold;" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" width="500px">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="font-size:72px;font-weight:bold;color:White;background-color:#B0B0B0; border:solid 3 #5A5A5A">INITIALISATION</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="font-size:16px"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="color:#5A5A5A">DOWNLOADING FILES</td><td align="center"><img id="step1" src="images index/WAITING.png" alt="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" id="step1comment" style="font-size:18px;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;border:solid 3 Red;color:White; background:#FF8A8A;visibility:hidden;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="color:#5A5A5A">QUERY STATIC DATA</td><td align="center"><img id="step2" src="images index/WAITING.png" alt="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" id="step2comment" style="font-size:18px;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;border:solid 3 Red;color:White; background:#FF8A8A;visibility:hidden;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="color:#5A5A5A">QUERY DYNAMIC DATA</td><td align="center"><img id="step3" src="images index/WAITING.png" alt="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" id="step3comment" style="font-size:18px;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;border:solid 3 Red;color:White; background:#FF8A8A;visibility:hidden;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="color:#5A5A5A">LOADING TEXTS</td><td align="center"><img id="step4" src="images index/WAITING.png" alt="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" id="step4comment" style="font-size:18px;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;border:solid 3 Red;color:White; background:#FF8A8A;visibility:hidden;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center" id="continueanyway" style="visibility:hidden"><button style="color:#5A5A5A;font-size:24px;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;" onclick="ShowWebsite();">Go to website anyway</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="WEBSITE" style="width:100%;height:100%;visibility:hidden">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="main_content">
                <div id="header">
                    <div id="left">
                        <p id="serial">Serial Number:</p>
                        <p id="page">Compressor_Y</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right">
                        <p id="elektronikon">Elektronikon</p>
                        <p id="langs">
                            <span id="langs_description">Languages111</span>
                            <select id="language_select" onchange="load_language();">
                                <option>downloading...</option>
                            </select>
                        </p>
                        <p id="AC">
                            <span id="Access_Level_descr">Access Level</span>
                            <select id="access" onchange="check_access();">
                                <option value="User">User</option>
                                <option value="Full">Full</option>
                            </select>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="error"></div>
                <div id="checks">
                    <div id="checkbox_container"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="tables">
                    <div id="TABLELEFT_L1">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="ANALOGINPUTSbody"></table>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="STEPPEROUTPUTSbody"></table>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="ANALOGOUTPUTSbody"></table>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="COUNTERSbody"></table>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="CALCULATEDANALOGINPUTSbody"></table>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="CONVERTERSbody"></table>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="SPMbody"></table>
                    </div>
                    <div id="TABLERIGHT_L1">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="MACHINESTATEbody"></table>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="DIGITALINPUTSbody"></table>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="DIGITALOUTPUTSbody"></table>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="SPECIALPROTECTIONSbody"></table>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="SERVICEPLANbody"></table>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="IDATAbody"></table>
                    </div>
                    <div id="TABLELEFT_L12">
                        <table id="CONVERTORFLOWbody"></table>
                    </div>
                    <table id="units" align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td  id="PRESSUREUNITstr" align="right">Pressure Unit:111</td>
                            <td align="left">
                            <select id="P" onchange="setProperties();">
                                <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
                                <option value="dBar">dBar</option>
                                <option value="mBar">mBar</option>
                                <option value="psi">psi</option>
                                <option value="kPa">kPa</option>
                                <option value="MPa">MPa</option>
                                <option value="kg/cm²">kg/cm²</option>
                                <option value="mmHg">mmHg</option>
                                <option value="inHg">inHg</option>
                                <option value="Torr">Torr</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td  id="TEMPERATUREUNITstr" align="right">Temperature Unit:111</td>
                            <td align="left">
                            <select id="T" onchange="setProperties();">
                                <option value="°C">°C</option>
                                <option value="°F">°F</option>
                                <option value="K">K</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td  id="ENERGYUNITstr" align="right">ENERGY Unit:111</td>
                            <td align="left">
                            <select id="E" onchange="setProperties();">
                                <option value="kWh">kWh</option>
                                <option value="MWh">MWh</option>
                                <option value="kBTu">kBTu</option>
                                <option value="MBTu">MBTu</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td  id="FLOWUNITstr" align="right">Flow Unit:111</td>
                            <td align="left">
                            <select id="F" onchange="setProperties();">
                                <option value="l/s">l/s</option>
                                <option value="cfm">cfm</option>
                                <option value="l/min">l/min</option>
                                <option value="m3/h">m³/h</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table id="tablees_l3">
                        <tr><td>
                            <table id="tableCompressors1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" style="border-width:1px;border-color:Black;border-style:solid"></table>
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>
                            <table id="tableDryers" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" style="border-width:1px;border-color:Black;border-style:solid;margin:50px 0px 0px 0px"></table>
                        </td></tr>
                    </table>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                    <span id="load_time">loading...</span><br />
                    v4.4.1.0
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="left_side">
            <a id="logo_link" href=""><img src="images/Brandlogo.gif" alt="brand logo" /></a>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li id="link1str" onclick="load_compressor();" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'">Compressor111</li><!---->
                    <li id="link2str" onclick="load_es();" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'">ES</li>
                    <li id="link3str" onclick="load_preferences();" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'">Preferences111</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`enter code here`
</body>
</html>
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/kEtLSf6b.png

